# Linking multiple tables with an Oracle outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Struggling with Oracle outer join syntax.

We have this query with inner and outer joins;

```
SELECT A.aa, B.bb, C.cc, D.dd
FROM
  TABLEA A, TABLEB B, TABLEC C, TABLED D
WHERE
  A.XX = B.XX AND
  B.YY = C.YY AND
  C.ZZ = D.WW (+)
```

The query works fine.  A change is now it's possible that the link between table A and B (on XX) may not be present.

So we'd like to turn this into an outer join which returns data regardless of whether the existing joins are satisfied OR if there is no link between A and B (and the other tables).

How can you do this?

Comment: This is the old way of writing this, look in to using the JOIN command.

Comment: Say you have a row in A not linked to B and rows in B, C, D linked together, but not with A. Do you want to extract a single row with the only values from A?

Comment: Yes single row with just A details.  And values from other tables would be null.

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the old `(+)` Use an explicit `left join` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have your tables like the following:

```
insert into tableA values (1);
insert into tableA values (2);
insert into tableB values ( 1, 10);
insert into tableB values ( -2, 20);
insert into tableC values ( 10, 100);
insert into tableC values ( 20, 200);
insert into tableD values ( 200);
insert into tableD values ( 999);
```

If I understand well, you need to use on outer join even on B and C, not only D; in the old Oracle syntax this is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  TABLEA A, TABLEB B, TABLEC C, TABLED D
WHERE
  A.XX = B.XX(+) AND
  B.YY = C.YY(+) AND
  C.ZZ = D.WW (+)
```

And in (better) ANSI SQL:

```
select *
from tableA A
       left outer join
     tableB B on ( A.xx = B.xx)
       left outer join 
     tableC C on ( B.yy = C.yy)
       left outer join
     tableD D on ( C.zz = D.ww)
```

They both give:

```
        XX         XX         YY         YY         ZZ         WW
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2
         1          1         10         10        100
```

Comment: Thanks.  Only comment is that if link exists between A and B then we are guaranteed to have a link between B and C so that doesn't need to be outer.  C and D are not guaranteed to link so outer is required there.

Comment: @MarcusLeon Don't forget to mark his answer as correct if it is, or at least upvote if it is helpful!

Comment: Will do.  I'm going to do some testing with this in the next couple days to see if it works for me.